What is the significance of three days?
Genesis 40:12

And Joseph said unto him, This is the interpretation of it: The three branches are three days:

Exodus 8:27

We will go three days’ journey into the wilderness, and sacrifice to the Lord our God, as he shall command us.

Exodus 10:22

And Moses stretched forth his hand toward heaven; and there was a thick darkness in all the land of Egypt three days:

Is there a significance to three days?

Michael Brown writes in his Jewish Objections to Jesus, Vol. 3. Messianic Prophecy Objections.  [Foonote page 352]  …

“Based on this biblical data, the German biblical scholar Roland
Gradwohl argued that “ ‘three days’ is a stereotyped phrase used by
the Old Testament in describing a situation when something will be
fulfilled or completed within a useful and reasonable time.… The
‘third day’ is used to describe the moment when an event attains its
climax.” Another German scholar, K. Lehmann, wrote an entire volume on
the subject of resurrection on the third day, pointing to passages
such as Exodus 19:11, 16; Genesis 22:4; 2 Kings 20:5; Esther 5:1;
Hosea 6:2 as evidence that the third day was associated with special
divine activity, something that caught the attention of the ancient
rabbis as well. These insights, coupled with some key verses about
restoration, salvation, or rescue from death on the third day, give
Paul the right to say that the Messiah rose from the dead on the third
day according to the Scriptures. There would have been no day more
suitable than this, from the viewpoint of the Word of God.


I wrote about this elsewhere.
I think proverbially the third day is when something lost is found; if it is not, it is gone for good.
Targum Jonathan of Hosea 6 relates the third day to the resurrection.
Hosea 6, Targum Jonathan


They will say,’ “Come let us return to the worship of the Lord: or he who struck us’ will heal us; he who brought destruction upon us
will relieve us.

He will give us life in the days of consolations that will come; on the day of the resurrection of the dead” he will raise us up and we
shall live before him.




According to Rev. Jeff Palmer of Crossroads Christian Church:

The number 3 biblically represents divine wholeness, completeness and
perfection. If there ever was a desire to highlight an idea, thought,
event or noteworthy figure in the Bible for their prominence, the
number 3 was used to put a divine stamp of completion or fulfillment
on the subject.

Old Testament

three levels of Noah’s ark
the three flights of the dove from the ark
after the flood
the three offerings of Abraham
and the three-day journey before the sacrifice of Isaac.
At the time of Moses there were: the three-day plague of darkness,
the three days of purification at the start of the Exodus, the three forty-year periods for the journey to Canaan
the three days of purification under Joshua’s leadership
just prior to crossing the Jordan River.

New Testament

In the life of Jesus we see: three decades of
private life followed by three years of public ministry
the three wise men from the
East who brought three gifts
the three disciples, the three temptations
the three prayers in the garden of Gethsemane
Peter’s three denials
the three hours of darkness at the crucifixion
Jesus’ resurrection after three days in the tomb.

